# how to make loop on list inside if condition

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I need to check if user typed like : "Im good"
to respond him "have a nice day"

I know that what I typed is wrong but it's just for clarifying

I basicly want to check if the user typed: Im + (any word in my list)

```
mylist = ['good', 'great', 'fantastic', 'fine']

for word in mylist:

q = input('how are you?')
if q == 'Im' + word:

    print('Have a nice day')

else:
    print('Sorry for enter code herethat')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to hoist the `input()` in front of the loop?

```py
mylist = ['good', 'great', 'fantastic', 'fine']

q = input('how are you?')
for word in mylist:
    if q == 'Im ' + word:
        print('Have a nice day')
        break
else:
    print('Sorry for that')
```

Example sessions:

```
how are you?Im good
Have a nice day

how are you?Im great
Have a nice day

how are you?Im fantastic
Have a nice day

how are you?Im fine
Have a nice day

how are you?im fine
Sorry for that

how are you?foo
Sorry for that
```

Comment: yes it gives me false always. try it in VS

Comment: What is: `it gives me false always`?

Comment: when i type im good it gives me false and print sorry for that 
always

Comment: My test cases were: `"Im good"` and `"Im bad"` and I got the correct response in both cases.

Comment: it seems to be working as it should be but it's not. this for loop is looping on every string in my list and that means if i just run the code and typed im fine it's gonna give me false.

Comment: Basically i want to check if the word after "Im" is in mylist or not

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted: `"Im + (any word in my list)"`

Comment: Let me update my answer with some test cases....

Comment: I don't think you got me but you're close.

Imagine if you're talking to me and I told you "How are you?"
You're going to respond with "Im ...."
and if you said "im good", "im great", "Im fine", "Im perfect" I should respond you as you're doing good.

Comment: Well, I'd say: `"I'm fine"`, and your program would say `"Sorry for that"`. But that's no matter. Also see my updated test cases.

Comment: Thank you. That was what i want..

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have the right idea. Only thing I would change is use `in` to check if the user entered something in the given list. Then you have to break out of the loop if that case is met.

```
mylist = ['good', 'great', 'fantastic', 'fine']
q = input('how are you?: ')
for word in mylist:
    if q in mylist:
        print('Good to hear')
        break
    else:
        print('aww')
        break
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you actually ran that code.

Comment: I think i did...

Comment: How did it respond to inputs like: `foo`?

Comment: it will say "awww"

Comment: Ok, let me try it.....  Oh, but you've changed your code!

Comment: When I go back to your original post, I get: `aww
aww
aww
aww`

Comment: I would do no such thing as editing my post... neverrrr

Comment: `neverrrr` .... lol.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
mylist = ["good", "great", "fantastic", "fine"]

for word in mylist:
    print("How are you")
    q = input()
    req_t = "Im " + word
    if q == req_t:
        print('Have a nice day')
        break
    else:
        print('Sorry for enter code herethat')
```

Comment: it didn't work as it should be.. try it